# How to make the following join?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, informix

Q:

- I have a DataTable result from the following query:

---

```
SELECT UNIQUE a.crsnum_e ,  a.crsnum_e  || '/ ' || a.crstteng crs_name, b.period , b.crscls , c.crsday , c.from_lect , c.to_lect , c.to_lect - c.from_lect + 1 Subtraction, c.lect_kind 

FROM rg1course a , rg3crsgrp b , ct1table c , ct1tablelect d 

WHERE a.crsnum = b.crsnum 
AND b.crsnum = c.crsnum
AND b.crscls = c.crscls
AND b.batch_no = c.batch_no 
AND c.serial_key = d.serial_key  

AND d.lect_code = ....
AND b.batch_no = ....
```

- I have another DataTable:Consists of:(Comes from another database table).

---

```
batch_no p.k
crsnum   p.k
lect_code p.k
evaluation
```

What i would to do is to:

join the two datatables , where i need the `evaluation` column in the result even if it is = `null`. I mean i need always to get the `first datatable` even it it's not have any instance in the second data table.

How to do this with :

```
INFORMIX JOIN.
```

or

```
LINQ.
```

**The pimary keys(batch_no,crsnum,lect_code).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Informix, to specify an outer join you need to do the following:

```
FROM table1 t1, OUTER table2 t2
WHERE t1.batch_no = t2.batch_no and ...
```

The resulting dataset would be all records from table1 and any records from table2 that match on the WHERE condition (and NULLs where it doesn't match).

If you want to do this in LINQ, this article has a good explanation with examples: http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/06/10/c-left-outer-joins-with-linq/

Comment: That works, but it is an old-fashioned outer join notation that is peculiar to Informix. Most DBMS have similarly archaic notation for outer joins. The SQL-92 standard defined a standard JOIN notation, including LEFT OUTER JOIN, and you should aim to use that in all queries, instead of using the comma-separated list of table names in the FROM clause and joining conditions in the WHERE clause: `FROM rg1course a JOIN rg3crsgrp b ON a.crsnum = b.crsnum JOIN ct1table c ON b.crsnum = c.crsnum AND b.crscls = c.crscls AND b.batch_no = c.batch_no JOIN ct1tablelect d ON c.serial_key = d.serial_key`.